# How to Find & Replace?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this code and I'm wondering if it can be shorter?

I'm new to VBA and I'm starting with the Macro Recorder. The function is "Find & Replace". I know there must be a short code for this.

```
Sub TOs()
    '
    ' MACRO_TOS Macro    
    '    
    '
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting    
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting    

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "To=____________________________"   
        .Replacement.Text = ""    
        .Forward = True    
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue    
        .Format = False    
        .MatchCase = False    
        .MatchWholeWord = False    
        .MatchWildcards = False    
        .MatchSoundsLike = False    
        .MatchAllWordForms = False    
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute

    With Selection    
        If .Find.Forward = True Then    
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart    
        Else    
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd    
        End If  

        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne   

        If .Find.Forward = True Then    
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd    
        Else    
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart    
        End If

        .Find.Execute    
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: Also I have a text that can't find & replace because it has tabbed spaces between each word, any idea how to find to replace it?

Comment: This code is MS-Word code. Please clarify that in your tags by changing the tag from [tag:excel] to [tag:ms-word] otherwise it will show up in the wrong categories.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yeah my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `Replace:=wdReplaceAll` to replace all at once.
2. You can use `.MatchWildcards = True` to allow wildcards in `.Text` where spaces may occur. For example:
   `.Text = "To*=*____________________________"`

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveTo()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "To=____________________________"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'replaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Could the `.Clear` and `.Replacement.ClearFormatting` before the `With` and the `.Execute ...` after the `With` all be included in the `With` block?

Comment: @FreeMan You can of course include them into the `With` block. That's just because of a technical thing how the Macro Recorder records a macro. It dosn't generate perfect code.

Comment: "It dosn't generate perfect code" - **VERY** well aware of this!! Got to say, though, it's better looking than Excel's macro recorder generated code.

Answer (score 0):

None of MatchCase, MatchWholeWord, MatchAllWordForms, and MatchSoundsLike work with wildcards. Accordingly, the code could be reduced to:

```
Sub RemoveTo()
With Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "To[ =]@[_]{1,}"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Forward = True
  .Format = False
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

or even:

```
Sub RemoveTo()
With Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Execute FindText:="To[ =]@[_]{1,}", ReplaceWith:="", MatchWildcards:=True, _
    Forward:=True, Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindContinue, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```